# Does "content-encoding: gzip" necessarily mean the content is in gzip format?

Tags: netty

When a server response comes with "Content-Encoding: gzip", does it necessarily mean that the response body is in gzip format? I am decoding the incoming response body (perhaps incorrectly) and am getting a "Not in GZIP format" exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if it contains "Content-Encoding: gzip" it must be gzip compressed.